# XSLT grouping with for-each-group and using filled elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have a list of persons and i would like to group them with the name of the each person, then check which `<vitalDates>`node has value in it, and put it in grouped `<person>` node.

```mxml
<persons>
    <person>
        <name>Goethe, Johann Wolfgang von </name>
        <vitalDates>
            <earliest/>
            <latest/>
        </vitalDates>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Müthel, Lothar</name>
        <vitalDates>
            <earliest/>
            <latest/>
        </vitalDates>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Goethe, Johann Wolfgang von</name>
        <vitalDates>
            <earliest>1749</earliest>
            <latest>1832</latest>
        </vitalDates>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Müthel, Lothar</name>
        <vitalDates>
            <earliest>1896</earliest>
            <latest>1964</latest>
        </vitalDates>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Goethe, Johann Wolfgang von</name>
        <vitalDates>
            <earliest>1749</earliest>
            <latest>1832</latest>
        </vitalDates>
    </person>
</persons>
```

At the Moment I have this transformation:

```mxml
<persons>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="person" group-by="name">
        <person>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            </name>
            <vitalDates>
                <earliest>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/persons/person[name=current-grouping-key()]/vitalDates/earliest">
                        <xsl:if test=". != ''">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </earliest>
                <latest>
                    <!-- do the same? -->
                </latest>
            </vitalDates>
        </person>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</persons>
```

and  i get the this result:

```mxml
<persons>
    <person>
        <name>Goethe, Johann Wolfgang von</name>
        <vitalDates>
            <earliest>17491749</earliest>
            <latest></latest>
        </vitalDates>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Müthel, Lothar</name>
        <vitalDates>
            <earliest></earliest>
            <latest></latest>
        </vitalDates>
    </person>
</persons>
```

like you can see `<earliest>` element with value found two times, but I need to use just one value and i dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as you use `for-each-group`, instead of `/persons/person[name=current-grouping-key()]` you can and should simply use `current-group()`.

As for selecting the first item, use `(current-group()/vitalDates/earliest[normalize-space()])[1]`.

Comment: Thanks! can you elaborate about what ´earliest[normalize-space()])[1]´ does?

Comment: If you select a sequence with an expression `exp` then `(exp)[1]` gives you only the first item in that selected expression. So `current-group()/vitalDates/earliest[normalize-space()])` selects all `earliest` grandchildren in the current group which have non-empty content and the `(current-group()/vitalDates/earliest[normalize-space()]))[1]` serves to select only the first.  The `normalize-space()` predicate is just an idiom used more often in XSLT/XPath than `. != ''` as it remove white space before comparing.